# How to use statement functions with arrays in Fortran 90

Tags: matlab, fortran

I am translating a Matlab code into Fortran 90 and am trying to translate the following piece of code:

```
func= inline('x+ y+ z', 'x', 'y', 'z')
x(1)= 1, y(1)= 1, z(1)= 1

for n= 1:5
output= 5+ func(x(n), y(n), z(n))
x(n+ 1)= x(n)+ 1
y(n+ 1)= y(n)+ 1
z(n+ 1)= z(n)+ 1
end
```

In Fortran I am using the statement (inline) function as func(x, y, z)= x+ y+ z, however, I am not able to insert the array part into the function.

How can I negotiate the dependence on 'n' into the statement function? I am trying something like the following but am not quite there yet.

```
func(x, y, z)= x+ y+ z
x(1)= 1, y(1)= 1, z(1)= 1
do n= 1, 5
func(x(n), y(n), z(n))= x(n)+ y(n)+ z(n)
end
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is an extended and formatted comment rather than an answer.

The general advice with statement functions in modern Fortran is *Don't, just don't*.  They're not big and they're not clever.  They were also deprecated in, I think, the Fortran 90 standard so, to be pedantic, your requirements are inconsistent.

Beyond that, it's difficult to provide any specific advice.  If I understand the Matlab correctly the code you show is a convoluted way to calculate `5+3*1+3*2+...+3*5`.  In Fortran 90 you might write

```
sum([5, (3*k,k=1,5)])
```

to calculate that.

Perhaps if we knew more of the context of your problem we'd be able to provide better advice.

Answer (score 0):

I did realize that statement functions in modern Fortran is not the way to go. Instead I have created subroutines for the functions and then call them in the loop. This way all the values of the function in the loop can be put into an array (instead of just the last values). The correct piece of code looks like this:

```
    subroutine funcsub(func, x, y, z, funcn)
    implicit none
    real, dimension(funcn), intent(out) :: func
    real, dimension(funcn), intent(in) :: x, y, z
    integer, intent(in) :: funky
    func= x+ y+ z
    end subroutine funcsub

    do i= 1, 5 
    funcn= size(func)    
    call funcsub(func, x(i), y(i), z(i), funcn)
    x(i+ 1)= x(i)+ 1
    y(i+ 1)= y(i)+ 1
    z(i+ 1)= z(i)+ 1
    end do
```

Comment: Note the whole purpose of this is to use the same format for more complicated functions that are a pain to keep writing out a million times.